# Why can 59.95 be stored exact in double?

Tags: mysql, floating-point, precision

I created a new table in  MySql  `5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1`.

The table contains a `double` column `a` and a `float` column `b`. Both columns use IEEE 754 format. I stored the number 59.95 in both fields. The number cannot be represented as a finite number in binary.

The output of the float column is like this:

```
SELECT b*100000000 FROM `test` where id=1
```

> 5995000076.293945

and

```
SELECT * FROM `test` where b = "59.95"
```

has no results. Both as expected. However, for the double column, I get the following results:

```
 SELECT a*100000000 FROM `test` where id=1
```

> 5995000000

and

```
SELECT * FROM `test` where a = "59.95"
```

returns row with `id=1`.

It seems that the `double` column is able to store `59.95` precisely, although this number cannot be stored precisely in binary. How is this possible?

Comment: It's not stored exactly, but it has more digits so you can't see the error as easily.

Comment: @Barmar if thats the case, why would `SELECT * FROM test where a = "59.95"` return this row?

Comment: Have you read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When 52.95 is converted to IEEE-754 binary32 (used for `float`), the result is 59.950000762939453125. When it is converted to IEEE-754 binary64 (used for `double`), the result is 59.9500000000000028421709430404007434844970703125.

In the statement `` SELECT * FROM `test` where b = "59.95" ``, the text `59.95` is converted to a `double`, yielding 59.9500000000000028421709430404007434844970703125.

Attempting to select this from `float` data yields no results because no `float` data has the value 59.9500000000000028421709430404007434844970703125. It can only have the value 59.950000762939453125.

Attempting to select this from `double` data yields results because `double` data can have the value 59.9500000000000028421709430404007434844970703125.

You may be able to find the desired `float` data by selected based on a value converted to `float`, such as `CAST('59.95' AS FLOAT)`. Unfortunately, I am unfamiliar with SQL grammar and cannot be sure of the exact syntax needed.

Also note that in `a*100000000`, a rounding occurs, causing the result to be 5995000000 (which is representable in `double`) rather than 5995000000.00000028421709430404007434844970703125 (which is not).

Comment: How can I see the exact value that is stored in mysql? If I try `a*100000000000000` I get `5.99e15`.  If I do `Select a from ..` I only get `59.90`. I use phpMyAdmin to access the db

Comment: Ah, if I do `Select a-59` I get `0.8999999999999986`